# Keyword "unsafe" - before method or block of code?

Tags: c#, unsafe

Is there any difference between using keyword `unsafe` before method or before block of code?

Will it be wrong if I use it before method when i have only few lines of unsafe code and hundreds of safe code?

Comment: If you have hundreds of lines in a single method I'd hardly call it "safe", no matter what your modifiers say

Comment: I know, it was just example, coudnt find better word to describe it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a subjective answer but I'd use `unsafe` on the method level, like this:

```
private unsafe int MyFunc ( ... )
{
    ...
}
```

When you use `unsafe` inside the body of the function, it's hidden away and it's hard to find, while something like this should be very apparent. Everybody will read the function declaration but not everyone will go into the function body, unless they need to.

Having `unsafe` in the declaration makes it stand out more.

Comment: I do it like you, but does other unsafe operations work same as in unsafe mode?

Comment: @zgnilec I'm sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. Do you mean 'do other safe operations work the same when in unsafe mode'? If that's what you mean, the answer is yes: everything 'safe' works just as before. `unsafe` simply gives you the ability to declare and use pointers to various .NET types. Intermixing safe & unsafe code is fine, as long as you're careful not to corrupt memory and to clean up unmanaged resources that you use.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question: See C# 4.0 spec chapter: 18.1

> The unsafe features of C# are available only in unsafe contexts. An
> unsafe context is introduced by including an unsafe modifier in the
> declaration of a type or member, or by employing an unsafe-statement:
>
> • A declaration of a class, struct, interface, or delegate may include
> an unsafe modifier, in which case the entire textual extent of that
> type declaration (including the body of the class, struct, or
> interface) is considered an unsafe context.
>
> •  A declaration of a
> field, method, property, event, indexer, operator, instance
> constructor, destructor, or static constructor may include an unsafe
> modifier, in which case the entire textual extent of that member
> declaration is considered an unsafe context.
>
> •  An unsafe-statement
> enables the use of an unsafe context within a block. The entire
> textual extent of the associated block is considered an unsafe
> context.

The second one: Of course it's **NOT WRONG** according to the conclusion of the first question. But I'd prefer wrap a few lines of unsafe codes with `unsafe` statement, because it's more clearer and easy to find.

Answer (score 1):

Unsafe code allows you to address the memory directly and as such it can have pros and cons. I have done some reading in regards to your question through this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2363/Unsafe-programming-in-C and I hope it might lead you in the right direction. Good luck!